# В какой кодировке строки в функциях SDL

Tags: c, sdl2

Я не совсем понимаю, с какой кодировкой работают функции **SDL** (конкретно **SDL2**).

Например:

```
SDL_Surface *SDL_LoadBMP(const char *);
const char *SDL_GetError();
```

Это **utf-8**?

Восьмибитная кодировка в системной локали?

**Latin-1**?

Comment: По идее должна быть UTF-8. Можете проверить и рассказать нам. :)

Comment: Хотелось бы знать наверняка)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [миграционному гайду](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide) одним из ключевых изменений была поддержка юникода. Все строки для событий текстового ввода идут в UTF-8. 
Кроме того [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) явно указывает что ожидает UTF-8. 
Вероятнее всего верный ответ это UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем ходить вокруг да около, если [у нас есть исходники](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33)?

[SDL_LoadBMP](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/include/SDL_surface.h#l200) — это макрос, передающий file в функцию SDL_RWFromFile без изменений.

В функции [SDL_RWFromFile](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/src/file/SDL_rwops.c#l511) есть всякий разный платформозависимый код:

- для Android используется по возможности fopen, а если нет, то [Android_JNI_FileOpen](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/src/core/android/SDL_android.c#l1404), которая использует функцию [NewStringUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF), которая принимает некий [modified UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16542);
- для Windows используется [windows_file_open](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/src/file/SDL_rwops.c#l74), которая с помощью макроса [WIN_UTF8ToString](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/src/core/windows/SDL_windows.h#l43) (в котором SDL_iconv_string) получает виндовую UTF-16LE строку из входой строки в кодировке UTF-8;
- для систем Apple внутри [SDL_OpenFPFromBundleOrFallback](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f1084c419f33/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m#l35) используется fopen, точной информации про который не нашлось, но ФС использует UTF-8;
- для Windows RT используется [fopen_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx), точную информацию о кодировке которой я тоже не нашёл, но если она подобна функции [fopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), то вероятно используется [формат ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format);
- для всех остальных систем file передаётся в fopen без изменений, а кодировка зависит от платформы и настроек системы, хотя у современных Unix-подобных ОС это чаще всего UTF-8.

Таким образом, если я правильно интерпретировал исходники и документацию, получается ответ — **зависит от платформы и параметров сборки**.

Возможно, в других функциях SDL, не связанных с файловой системой, используется строго UTF-8, но, видимо, уже от одной лишь SDL_LoadBMP можно нахватать проблем.

---

Между прочим, [документация про SDL_RWFromFile](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromFile) заявляет, что используется UTF-8. Получается, врёт?

Comment: Как же все сложно. Я тут думал, как совладать с зоопарком кодировок, а проблема, оказывается, более фундаментальная. Значит, есть смысл везде использовать только латиницу? Ведь символы **ascii** и **utf-8** с кодами 0-127 совпадают.

Comment: "Получается, врёт?" скорее всего просто недоделки по принципу "good enough".